# Pybrain multi dimensional data input

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I have some data that has a **dimension** of **8x128** for each record. I wanted to train a Neural Network for this data.

Does anyone have any examples of using **Multi-Dimensional** Data as Input to a Pybrain Neural Network?
I've searched the documentation and found only Single Dimensional Input examples. [enter link description here](http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/netmodcon.html#netmodcon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neural Networks don't care about the dimensionality of your input data, just serialize it (reshape([1024])) and feed that as input.