# PyBrain addSample multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pybrain

In all of the examples it seems that addSample(input, target) is used with 1 dimensional arrays, such as:

```
INPUT = 5
OUTPUT = 1

input = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
target = [1]

ds = SequentialDataSet(5, 1)
#add data using addSample
```

How does one do this when the input is multi-dimensional in this way:

```
input = [[5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
target = [1]
```

How does one use addSample with such structures? I tried this:

```
ds = SequentialDataSet(2, 1)
ds.addSample(input, target)
```

and get the error message:

```
Could not broadcast input array from shape (2, 5) into shape 2.
```

Meaning the SequentialDataSet(2, 1) does not work for this structure, but SequentialDataSet((2, 5), 1) also errors. This should be easy but I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *looks* like you're trying to train some sort of Feed Forward network, perhaps a multi-layer perceptron? 5 layers in, one or more hidden layers, and a single output layer but it's not clear so this is a leap on my end.

Either way your input layer should be a single array. If you have a structure, or multi-dimensional array you'll need to collapse it and feed it in as a single set of data. So for your 5x2 suggestion you'd simply have 10 elements on the input, and you would be responsible for "parsing" your input structures consistently as they're fed into the network. For a 5x5 structure you'd have 25 inputs etc.

In my experience a big part of the success/challenge with ANNs is structuring the data in so that the input form is normalized and represented in a way that the network can mathematically find a pattern with.

Comment: So I need to reshape the 5x2 into a 10x1 array, isn't that odd that it cannot take a 5x2 array, results should be different with a 5x2 compared to a 10x1 correct? Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

According to the post linked beneath you should just input one array:

[Pybrain multi dimensional data input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400169/pybrain-multi-dimensional-data-input)

For SequentialDataSet I used this example:

```
data = [(1,2), (1,3), (10,2), (2,0), (2,9), (4,3), (1,2), (10,5)]
ds = SequentialDataSet(2,2)
for sample, next_sample in zip(data, cycle(test_data[1:])):
   ds.addSample(sample, next_sample)
```